# How to preserve real number's precision

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-bases

`RealDigits[523.502]` gives me `{{5, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 3}`. Is there a way in run time to tell Mathematica not to offer high precision, ie, preserve whatever precision the input is given (returning `{{5, 2, 3, 5, 0, 2}, 3}` for the above)?

Please be mindful that the input can be any real number, I will not know the exact precision when I call this function.

Comment: Related: [(71572)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71572/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may seem counter-intuitive, but what works is to rationalize the number first,

```
Rationalize[523.502]
(* 261751/500 *)
```

This allows us to take advantage of the following property of [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html)

> For integers and rational numbers with terminating digit expansions, `RealDigits[x]` returns an ordinary list of digits.

Combining the two then will give you what you are looking for,

```
RealDigits @ Rationalize @ 523.502

(* {{5, 2, 3, 5, 0, 2}, 3} *)
```

Comment: This does not appear to be robust, e.g. `RealDigits @ Rationalize[12.345678]` gives `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 2}` in v10.1 under Windows x64.